# In php: How to set <select name=[php variable name] >?

Tags: php

```
for($i=0; $i++; $i<4)
{
    $nameselected = "a".$i;
    echo "<select name="$nameselected" onChange='document.changet_form.submit()'>
              <option value="apple">Volvo</option>
              <option value="orange">Saab</option>
              <option value="grape">Opel</option>
              <option value="mango">Audi</option>
          </select>";
}
```

Get the name of :

```
if(($_REQUEST[$nameselected]) == "a0")
```

Hi, How to set the select name=[php variable name]  ?
The way i set and get is it correct?
THANK YOU :)

Comment: Please consult google for at least 10 minutes prior to posting on this site.

Comment: Also, instead of asking if it works, try it...

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky also the `for` loop is wrong should be `for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)`

Comment: @bansi oops yes thats true

Comment: `$nameselected` will be `a0`...`a3` and `$_REQUEST[$nameselected]` will contain whatever is posted (selected in corresponding dropdown). Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $nameselected = "a".$i;
    echo '<select name="' . $nameselected . '" onChange="document.changet_form.submit()">
              <option value="apple">Volvo</option>
              <option value="orange">Saab</option>
              <option value="grape">Opel</option>
              <option value="mango">Audi</option>
          </select>';
}
```

I think you made a typo in your for loop!

Comment: Why the double-double quotes?

Comment: @bansi Is a matter of opinion. But OP's code should work now!

Comment: if(($_REQUEST[$nameselected]) == "a0")

But this code can get the variables?

Comment: You have to use quotes like this: `if(($_REQUEST['$nameselected']) == "a0")`

Comment: @Nnnnikkiiiiiii Do you need any more help? Or is your question answered?

Comment: I haven solve my problem... If i use [echo "] instead of [echo '], is it become [echo "<select name '".$nameselected.'" ............] ?

Comment: @Nnnnikkiiiiiii no if you want to use: `echo "..."` the line would look like this: `echo "<select name='" . $nameselected . "' onChange...`

Comment: @Nnnnikkiiiiiii if you have more questions you can ask another one! (BTW: you can accept answer how helped you! If you need more information about SO see: http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @Nnnnikkiiiiiii I don't even have a index in my code? What do you mean? Also since you accepted it has it worked?

Comment: `if (isset($_REQUEST['del_idd']))
{
 echo $_REQUEST['$myselect'];
}

$myselect = "hello";
echo "<select name='".$myselect."' onchange='document.del_id_form.submit()'>
        <option value=\"1\">One</option>
        <option value=\"2\">Two</option>
        <option value=\"3\">Three</option>
        <option value=\"4\">Four</option>
</select>";`

My codes like this... but doesn't work >.<